# “Every day in every way, I’m getting better and better.”

Tags: english-to-german, poetry

Ich suche eine sinngemäße poetische Übersetzung. Denn die wörtliche („Jeden Tag werd ich in jeder Hinsicht besser.“) klingt schauderhaft.

Ich dachte an etwas der Art:

> Jeden Tag, mit jeder Tat, geht’s mir besser und besser.

Aber das überzeugt mich nicht.

Comment: Was soll es denn nun heißen? Der Unterschied zwischen _ich werde besser_ und _mir geht es besser_ ist ja nicht gerade klein.

Comment: @chirlu Na ja, das englische ``get better`` ist überladen. Wenn ich traurig/depressiv/etc. bin kann ich auch ``get better`` - nicht im Sinne, dass ich dann besser *bin* sondern dass es mir besser *geht*.

Comment: Ist mir schon klar; aber ohne Kontext läßt sich nicht entscheiden, welche Übersetzungen überhaupt in Betracht kommen.

Comment: @chirlu oh ... sorry. Ich suche eine Übersetzung, wo das ``get better`` dahingehend verstanden wird, dass es der Person besser *geht*.

Comment: Wenn du dabei immer noch nach etwas suchst, das poetisch klingt, wirst du wohl ziemlich frei übersetzen müssen. Finde "jeden Tag, mit jeder Tat" ist ein guter Anfang. Dann vielleicht "werd' ich besser und besser". An die Wand hängen, aus der Entfernung anstarren und einen Thesaurus darauf werfen.

Comment: *Jeder meiner Tage wird mit jeder meiner Taten - immer ein bißchen besser* hört sich für mich hinreichend poetisch an - Ist aber nur **ähnlich**

Comment: "Mit jedem Tag geht es mir besser." Oder "Tag für Tag geht es mir besser." Nicht sonderlich poetisch...

Comment: Ich komme bei [diesem Schema](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/a/1104/15318) auf *nicht schließen.*

Comment: @Jan: Alle vier vorliegenden Schließstimmen sind wegen _primarily opinion-based_. Das Flußdiagramm ist darauf nicht anwendbar.

Comment: @chirlu Ich bin nicht der Meinung, dass POB der Fall ist, deswegen habe ich auch soeben für Wiederöffnen gestimmt.

Answer (score 1):

Also meiner Einschätzung nach stammt der Ausgangssatz aus der Ecke Autosuggestion und Selbstmanagement-Seminar und hat mit Poesie nicht viel zu tun. Es ist auch sehr die Frage, ob eine poetische Formulierung einem solchen Mantra hilfreich ist.

Aus meiner Sicht ist die vorgeschlagene Übersetzung *es geht mir .. besser* unglücklich, weil hier das *Ich* zum Objekt wird und damit der Zweck, für sich selbst die Initiative zu ergreifen, verloren geht. Zumindest im gemäß Kommentar reduziertem Teilaspekt sollte es eher heißen:

> Ich fühle mich von Tag zu Tag besser

Answer (score -1):

"in every way" würde ich mit "in jeder Hinsicht" übersetzen.

Und  "I'm getting better" vestehe ich eher als "ich werde besser" oder "ich wachse" (in seelischer Hinsicht - nicht an Körpergröße ;-) ).

Comment: Danke, aber du solltest die Frage vielleicht nochmals lesen. =)

Comment: –1. Geht vollkommen an der gestellten Frage vorbei.

Comment: Ich dachte jetzt an Hilfe zur Selbsthilfe, also evtl. neue Eingebungen, wie du deine poetische Formulierung selber formulieren kannst. Daher geht die "-1" auf keinen Fall in Ordnung. Sei's drum.